# Can EMF be expressed in weber/second?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I had a school exam yesterday and there was this question where I was asked to find the instantaneous EMF of a falling rod due to the magnetic field of the earth. The units of the magnetic field was given as weber/m<sup>2</sup>. During the exam I was not sure about the conversion of weber into tesla. Therefore I wrote the value of the EMF with units of weber/second. I thought it should be right as EMF can be expressed as the rate of change of flux.
Was I correct? 
[image: Here's The question]

Comment: According to, e.g., Wikipedia, the unit Weber can be expressed as Volt-seconds.  Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this picture of Tesla on Serbian money will help :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that volt = weber/second

$[\mathcal E]=\left [ \dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\right ] = \left [ \dfrac{d(BA)}{dt}\right ]$

LHS $\Rightarrow\,\rm V$
RHS $\Rightarrow\; \dfrac{\rm T m^2}{\rm s}=\Rightarrow\; \dfrac{\rm Wb\,m^{-2}m^2}{\rm s}=\rm Wb\,s^{-1}$

Answer (score -1):

Nope.  Induced Voltage is in volts.

Flux density B is in T which are $Wb/m^2$

$V_{Induced} = N B l v = 1 turn \times 0.3 \times 10^{-4} T \times 10m \times 5 m/s = 1.5\times 10^{-3}Wb/s $

$1 Wb = 1 V\cdot s$

$V_{Induced} = 1.5\times 10^{-3}Wb/s = 1.5\times 10^{-3} V\cdot s/s = 1.5 mV $

Edit...

wrt OP.

If you look up definition of EMF, it is clearly defined in volts.

wrt comment(s).

I see a student, who is looking for wiggle room to justify why their incorrect answer is correct.  I showed them how to get there.

Although not one of the fundamental metric units, there is a strong argument for volts because of the different methods emf can be generated.  If $1.5\times 10^{-3}Wb/s$ is valid, then an AAA or AA battery producing 1.5Wb/s or an outlet being 120 Wb/s at 60Hz are just as valid.  That just does not make sense.

Comment: you seem to be contradicting yourself: first you say nope (meaning presumably that the EMF cannot be expressed as $Wb/s$) and then you calculate it in $Wb/s$ which you point out is the same as $V$. Can you clarify?